# Python Outlook Sent Folder

Tags: python, email, outlook

I created an automated email sender in Python for Outlook.  It works fine, but I was wondering if it is possible to save the emails it sends in the sent folder. I'm sure there is, but I am unsure where to begin.  Any help would be appreciated.

This is in Python 3.6

======

```
from tkinter import *
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
import csv
import time
import warnings


root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x200')

email_label = Label(root, text="Enter your email")
email_label.pack()

username = Entry(root, width = 30)
username.pack()

password_label = Label(root, text="Enter your password")
password_label.pack()

password = Entry(root, show="*", width = 30)
password.pack()

def add_var():
    user_name = username.get()
    pass_word = password.get()
    with open("emailtk.csv") as f:
        try:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
            time.sleep(3)
                address = row[0]
                first_name = row[1]
                last_name = row[2]
                name = first_name+' '+last_name
                company = row[4]
                msg = MIMEMultipart()
                msg["To"] = address
                msg["From"] = user_name
                msg["Subject"] = subject
                print("Will now send an email to %s at %s at %s" % (name, company, address))
                msgText = MIMEText("""
                                Hello %s!
                                """ % (name), 'html')
                msg.attach(msgText)   # Added, and edited the previous line

                time.sleep(5)

                smtp = smtplib.SMTP('Outlook.com', 25)
                smtp.ehlo()
                smtp.starttls()
                smtp.login(user_name,pass_word)
                smtp.sendmail(user_name, address, msg.as_string())
                print("email sent")
                print("======================")
                print()
                smtp.quit()
```

Comment: How are you sending the emails?  My implementation using `win32com` puts the emails in the sent folder as expected.

Comment: Via smtp. I'll put the code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending via SMTP will not copy the messages into the Sent Items folder. You will need to use Outlook Object Model (via win32com) or EWS (in case of Exchange Server).

**UPDATE**: as of Summer 2019, messages sent through Office 365 SMTP servers are saved in the Sent Items folder of the sending account mailbox.

Comment: Or use IMAP to place it in the Sent folder.

Comment: That wouldn't be the same message sent by Outlook (MIME headers and all) - it will be a fake message created by your code.

Comment: How do you think standard IMAP/SMTP clients do it?  They place the same message they submit via SMTP into IMAP (although, possibly with BCC headers added).

Comment: True, but Outlook generally speaking does not do that - MIME is not its native format.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to accept your answer. In any case, I ended up putting the message into a variable (not MIMEText, but what it contains) and had the program append that to a text file.